# Xcodebuild CarbonCore Error while running lunch

Tags: android, xcode, compilation

I am trying to compile Android form source on my Mac (OS 10.9 Mavericks) 
But when I run `lunch aosp_arm-eng`

I get

> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36732] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() =>
>   (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36732] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamInvalidate(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36732] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:12.063 xcodebuild[36732:2007]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream.
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36766] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() =>
>   (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36766] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamInvalidate(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36766] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:12.981 xcodebuild[36766:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36803]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[36803] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36803] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:13.885 xcodebuild[36803:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36838]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[36838] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36838] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:14.808 xcodebuild[36838:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36869]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[36869] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36869] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:15.829 xcodebuild[36869:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36900]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[36900] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36900] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:16.797 xcodebuild[36900:2407]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36931]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[36931] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36931] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:17.822 xcodebuild[36931:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36966]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[36966] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[36966] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:18.871 xcodebuild[36966:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[37001]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[37001] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[37001] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:19.932 xcodebuild[37001:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream. 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[37035]
>   (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server:
>   ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21) 2014-07-02 19:16
>   xcodebuild[37035] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16 xcodebuild[37035] (CarbonCore.framework)
>   FSEventStreamRelease(): failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> 2014-07-02 19:16:20.971 xcodebuild[37035:30b]  DVTFilePathFSEvents:
>   Failed to start fs event stream.

[EDIT]
Updating command line tools fixed the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Command line tools though App Store and make sure you have the Xcode Installed